# Is it possible to get access to flight logs of USAAC trainer planes from the 1930s?

Tags: flight-training, usa, military, logging

After answering [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/12233/u-s-biplane-identification) on History.SE, I started to wonder if it would be possible to find out even more detail about the plane now that its serial number is known.

I have no idea what kind of flight records the US Army Air Corps kept, however. I know most flight logs today are kept by pilot, but I imagine there would be some way to trace what pilots flew a particular plane. I have no idea if this is possible for USAAC trainer planes in the 1930s.

Could I get access to these records? If so, how would I go about it?

I'm mostly interested in seeing if I can find out more information about where the plane flew, and maybe (if I'm lucky) who flew it when and for what purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For serial number 31-35
 - Pilot seems to be Brookley, Wendell H 
 - Homebase seems to have been Wright Field, Dayton, OH

[See Link](http://www.aviationarchaeology.com/src/1940sB4/1934.htm)

For serial number 31-85
 - Pilot seems to be Larkin, James D.
 - Homebase seems to have been Boeing Field, Seattle, WA

[See Link](http://www.aviationarchaeology.com/src/dbahb.asp?HB=boeing&offset=-1)

[It seems that you can order any of these Reports.](http://www.aviationarchaeology.com/src/reports.htm)